# How to show the time of a post being posted using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have no idea how to render the time of a post being posted on my blog. I am using express as backend and template engine (express-edge).

Comment: Posts are saved in a database right? Whenever the post gets posted add a new column to your database table name it `DATE_POSTED` or whatever and fetch the current date and time and append it to that column, then when you are rendering the post just fetch that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-js if you need to translate a date into anothers langages

you could also just use this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat